# PostgreSQL risks of force terminating a session using pg_terminate_backend

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have learned that you can terminate a session accessing a table by performing

```
SELECT t.relname, l.locktype, pid, mode, GRANTED
FROM pg_locks l INNER JOIN pg_stat_all_tables t ON l.relation = t.relid
ORDER BY relation asc;
```

and then terminating the PID accessing your relation by using

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(xxx);
```

But what are the potential risks and downsides of doing so? 
Is it bad practice to use `pg_terminate_backend(xxx);` frequently? (as part of a routine execution)
Is it always safe to terminate the session? 
Assuming the session is JDBC, would it result in anything else than an SQLException being thrown at the terminated session?

The use case is terminating a session reading from table before table is being refreshed, since reads would be bad anyway. The JDBC session will handle the SQLException accordingly.

Comment: Why do you need it regularly? We only use it when some proces is broken and doesn’t end by itself. Bugs like that happen maybe once every 2 or 3 years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only risk you have, is that any changes that are not yet committed by that session will be rolled back when you terminate the session.

The correct solution however, is to investigate the root cause *why* you need this so frequently. This sounds like a bug in your application.

Comment: Two applications share the same database and nothing else in between, the idea would be to avoid more coupling between the two services. The write application would act like a "master" and have priority on the table and not care about others, the reading service should do so only when the table is not being modified otherwise it's possible to get a bad read. The information is not that time sensitive so it's only refreshed once in a while. I cannot afford to use transactions to perform writes because there's too much data, keeping potentially two sets during transactions would be too expensive

Comment: @TeddyTsai: Readers and writers don't have to block each other, that only happens when you want them to block each other. We have over 200 applications and about 5 million customers reading and writing from/to a single database. Use the right transaction setting and you don't have any problem at all.

Comment: If you use the default `READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation level, reading sessions see modified data as soon as they are committed. So there is no need to cancel sessions, that will only lead to errors, the need to repeat operations as hence to increased load.

Comment: What I would need in this particular use case is for writers to block/kick readers, since reads are on the whole table and need to happen on consistent data, but readers should not ever block writers. On a purely technical aspect yes, Access Share and RowExclusive Locks don't conflict, but the data you read might not be complete.